# Windows 10 Session restarting + no graphic card

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, display-driver

I have a weird issue:
My setup has **2 screens** plugged with DVI, and **one TV** with HDMI, all on my **GTX460** video card (drivers up to date).

Sometimes (I think it's when I am gaming and watching video, it did not happen if I was passively watching a video), my two screens go black (but I see the cursor), and on my TV I see the Windows session logging off to restart, but the 2 monitors stay black, I only see a fresh window session on the TV.

Then I check on the TV the drivers, and my graphic card is not here, it is using the integrated graphics from the motherboard.

Comment: Are there any messages in the event log? Any scheduled tasks that run updates? Are you using a laptop or a desktop?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your graphics card driver, AKA Nvidia Control Panel is crashing. I had this happen on a few of my PC's, and the root of the problem seemed to be a malfunctioning graphics card. If possible, try to insert the card into another PC and see if the same problem occurs there. If not, try another graphics card in your PC and see if it still happens, if so, you will have to do further troubleshooting.

Would it be possible to upload a picture of the problem? Also, check your Computer Logs by going to **Computer Management** -> **Windows Logs** -> **Application**.